What is the default IV length and size used by Bouncy castle when encrypting data with AES in GCM mode?
I am currently working on a project that involves encrypting data using AES in Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) with a Bouncy castle. I need to understand the default settings used by the Bouncy castle for the Initialization Vector (IV) when performing AES-GCM encryption.
Specifically, I would like to know:

What is the default IV length used by the bouncy castle for AES-GCM encryption?
What is the default IV size in bytes?
Additionally, I need this information for Bouncy castle version 1.70.
Any insights or references to official documentation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I have been working on encrypting data using AES in Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) with Bouncy Castle. I reviewed the Bouncy Castle documentation and searched online for information regarding the default Initialization Vector (IV) length and size used by Bouncy Castle when performing AES-GCM encryption. However, I couldn’t find specific details about the default IV settings for Bouncy Castle, particularly for version 1.70

For GCM mode, instead of IV, the terminology for the roughly analogous value is nonce.

Still I want to know default IV length used by the bouncy for AES-GCM encryption

Don't you supply the IV? In general a best practice for IV length with AES-GCM is 12 bytes. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41601/aes-gcm-recommended-iv-size-why-12-bytes
